# Как подкрутить прозрачности для фонового изображения на сайте?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, opacity

Нужно сделать фоновое изображение на сайте полупрозрачным. Я попробовал использовать:

```
* {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
body {
     background-image: url(...);
}
```

Но такое решение делает прозрачными и некоторые другие блоки, что мне не надо. Как можно по-другому реализовать прозрачность?

Comment: Ну `*` это же вообще всё-всё-всё. Тут лучше, как мне видится, с самой картинкой поработать. Либо же в отдельный див поместить бэкграунд, спозиционировать его и ему уже дать `opacity: .5`. Иначе всё будет полупрозрачным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать блок с `position: absolute` и растянуть его на все окно, ему же и задать `opacity`.
Картинку можно вставить как через css, так и через img.

Через CSS:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.cssbg {
  background: center / cover url("https://picsum.photos/1024/768");
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cssbg">

</div>

<div class="someContent">content</div>
```

Через img:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.bgimg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: -1;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img class="bgimg" src="https://picsum.photos/1024/768">
<div class="content">content</div>
```